# Find eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix

$$
        A = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

How should I find its eigenvalues without computing the characteristic polynomial? The solution I have says that, since $\text{rank}(A)=1$ and trace($A)$=3, then eigenvalues have to be $\{0,0,3\}$. I cannot follow this argument. What does rank have to do with eigenvalues here?

Comment: It is a rank-$1$ matrix and $3$ is an eigenvalue associated with the eigenvector $(1,1,1)$. It follows that $3$ is the only eigenvalue in the spectrum that differs from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Jordan form, if the rank is 1 then there is at most one Jordan block that is non zero (otherwise the rank would be greater than one) and
this block must have size one (otherwise the rank would be greater than one).

It follows that there is exactly one non zero eigenvalue.

The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues hence it is the value of the only
non zero eigenvalue.

Another approach is to note that any rank one matrix can be written in
the form $u v^*$, then since $\dim \ker v^*$ is one less than the dimension of the space and $u v^* u = (v^*u) u$ we see that $u v^*$ has exactly one
non zero eigenvalue which is $v^*u$. In the above case we have
$u=v = (1,1,1)^T$, hence the eigenvalue is $3$.

Answer (score 2):

$n-r=3-1=2$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero, where $r$ denotes the rank of $A$, and $n$ the size. Since the sum of all three eigenvalues equals the trace, we have $3=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0+0+\lambda_3$, hence $\lambda_3=3$.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is diagonalizable, the rank is the number of nonzero eigenvalues (counting with multiplicity) and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (counting with multiplicity). This matrix is diagonalizable because it is symmetric.

Comment: That first sentence is not quite correct in general; the rank is the dimension of the matrix minus the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$. The eigenvalue $0$ can be defective in which case the rank will be higher than you said.

Comment: OK, assume diagonalizability.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix whose rank is not full has a nontrivial kernel. Any vector in the kernel is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 0.